# Pytest generating a large number of lines at the end in travis output causing it to fail

Tags: pytest, travis-ci

I have a travis build on [github](https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker) that runs pytest. Locally everything works fine, but on travis pytest appear to be creating thousands of lines with the module names continuously repeated at the bottom after all the tests have passed. It's unclear to me what's causing this. Could it be a pytest issue? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can see the travis output [here](https://travis-ci.com/github/dickreuter/neuron_poker):

This is the [travis yaml file](https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
language: python


python:
  - "3.6"

os:
  - linux

install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then MINICONDA_OS=Linux; else MINICONDA_OS=MacOSX; fi
  - wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-$MINICONDA_OS-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p "$HOME"/miniconda
  - source "$HOME"/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no --set auto_update_conda false
  - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  - export COVERAGE_DIR=":$HOME/htmlcov"
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - printenv | sort
  - conda install gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64 -c anaconda

# command to run tests
script: pytest --log-cli-level=ERROR

after_success:
  - codecov
```

Using this [pytest.ini](https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/blob/master/pytest.ini):

```
[pytest]
addopts = -s
python_functions = test_*
```

Comment: You can pass `--disable-warnings` and disable all warnings. However, this won't solve the underlying issue - probably some third-party dependency emitting a warning without a message. Try changing the test invocation command to smth like `pytest -W error::Warning` - this should treat all warnings as errors and fail the test on any warning occurring. This should give you at least the stack trace to dig further.

Comment: but shouldn't I be able to reproduce it locally?

Comment: You will be able reproduce the issue locally if you recreate the travis build env locally, e.g. in a container.